# Implementing twitter oauth 1.0a flow using client side and server side

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, oauth, authorization

This may be a straightforward question by looking at the title, but I have a very specific situation.

I am implementing social login flow in a application. The auth providers are Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter.

The flow is, the client (JavaScript code) authenticates the user by means of a pop up and once user authenticates the requests the client will make an HTTP POST call to backend API server passing the `accessToken` that the client gets after authenticating the user.

The server will once again validate the `accessToken` and then generates a `sessionToken` and pass to client; the client now will use this `sessionToken` in future api calls to server.

Now for Facebook there is JS SDK and I got the access token. For LinkedIn also there is JS SDK and I have the `oauth_token` using

```
var oauthToken = IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token;
```

I passed this `oauthToken` to server; the server will make an HTTP request to people's API and get the user data. The request is like below for linkedin

```
request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': accessToken
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if(error) {
    callback(error);
  } else if(response.statusCode < HTTP_RANGE) {
    var result = JSON.parse(body);
    callback(null, result);
  } else {
    var err = JSON.parse(body);
    callback(err);
  }
});
```

And the above is working fine for linkedin also.

Now my questions are the following:

1. How can I achieve the same flow with Twitter? I read the [sign in with twitter flow at twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in) but I am not sure I would be able to implement it particularly signing the requests and parsing response. So for that I searched google but wasn't able to find any good libraries that can do it. Kindly suggest any good library.
2. Also if I consider the above flow it will expose the twitter client id and client secret on public JS code which is strongly not recommended. So I did some research and started with [oauth.io](https://oauth.io/). Using oauth.io I am able to let users login to application using pop up based mechanism. Code below

   ```
   // twitter social network login
   OAuth.popup('twitter').done(function(result) {
     console.log(result);
     // call backend api to login
     socialNetworkLoginHandler(socialNetwork, result.oauth_token); 
   }).fail(function (error) {
     $log.error('Twitter OAuth Error ' + angular.toJson(error));
   });
   ```

   The result object contains oauth_token, I passed this oauth token to server and will makes a call to twitter api to verify credentials like below

   ```
   request.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json', {
     'headers': {
       'oauth_token': accessToken
     }
   }, function(error, response, body) {
     if(error) {
       callback(error);
     } else if(response.statusCode < HTTP_RANGE) {
         var result = JSON.parse(body);
         callback(null, result);
     } else {
       var err = JSON.parse(body);
       callback(err);
     }
   });
   ```

   I am getting error from twitter api as bad authentication data, Error code 215. The above is working fine in LinkedIn but the same is failing in Twitter. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I’m looking for the same thing, but according to my research, this is not yet possible with Twitter. Facebook and Google provides official ways to do so; to add Twitter to your kit, you need an actual OAuth (the flow you described is not actually OAuth).